# Mapping array's with joins and gsub

Tags: ruby

I am trying to join an array using the `.map` feature, but I also need to escape single quotation marks. I'm currently doing this;

```
join_str = @record.map{|k,v|, "'#{v}'").join(",")
```

The `{v}` value needs to be wrapped around single quotes, however how do I modify this so I can escape single quotation marks that reside witin the `{v}` value?

For example;

`'Example'` **(CORRECT)**

`'This isn't acceptable'` **(BAD)**

`'You\'re onto a winner here!'` **(CORRECT)**

Comment: it is probably should be `"'#{v}'"`

Comment: can you show us a sample of @record ? that would help...

Comment: @Sam your code above has syntax errors, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the quotation marks by an escaped version.

```
@record.map { |_,v| "'#{v.to_s.gsub("'", "\\'")}'" }.join(',')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is kinda what I was after, however it doesn't work. I get a `NoMethodError Undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @Sam I guess that `v` can be nil. You can `nil` convert to a string with the `to_s()` method. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
join_str = @record.map{|k,v| "#{v}"}.join(",")
```

Comment: This won't work, `{v}` needs to be wrapped in single quotes. But the value of `{v}` may contain a single quote that needs to be escaped. I'm building a SQL query so it needs to be escaped.

Comment: @Sam: it's database driver's responsibility to escape things. You just have to use proper methods (parameterized queries instead of sql blob)

Comment: I'm building a load file that contains INSERT statements. I want to be able to then copy and paste the results into SQL Management Studio and run the query.